# Running Flask with Gunicorn raises TypeError: index() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to run a Flask app with Gunicorn.  When I run `gunicorn app:index`, I get the error `TypeError: index() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given`.  None of the examples I've seen show `index` needing two parameters.  What does this error mean?  How do I run Flask with Gunicorn?

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

```
gunicorn app:index
```

```
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
TypeError: index() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

I changed `index` to take two arguments, but got a different error.

```
@app.route("/")
def index(arg1, arg2):
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

```
  /python3.4/site-packages/flask/templating.py, line 132, in render_template
    ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to pass a Flask instance to `gunicorn`, not a function name like you did with `index`. So if your app saved as `app.py`, then you have to run `gunicorn` as follows:

```
$ gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 app:app
```

Comment: My filename was not `app.py` but I still needed to call `my_file_name:app`.  Seems to depend on the variable name defined here `app = Flask(__name__)`, `app` in this case.

Comment: @User actually this is exactly what I said in my answer, "pass a Flask instance". You assign a flask instance to the variable `app`

Comment: The answer is probably correct - or at least helps to find the cause of the issue - but IMO, it's easy to be confused by the sample code; to clarify: The OP called Gunicorn using `gunicorn app:index`, i.e. `<module name>:<function name>`; Gunicorn expects `<module name>:<Flask instance>`; `index()` returns that Flask instance, so Gunicorn should be called with parentheses after the function name: `gunicorn app:index()`

Comment: Also, note that the error typically occurs with Gunicorn, but not with the Flask development server (which seems to accept both function _name_ and function _call_; gives reason to assume that Flask internally checks the type and calls the function itself if parentheses are missing. Probably debatable, but IMO, Flask is concealing a bug in how it's called there...